# Fast post/comment extraction from instagram profiles using instaloader

Tags: python-3.x, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using `instaloader` to automatically grab the posts and comments of 50 big instagram profiles (over 8K posts and thousands of comments). I'm looking to update each profile every 30 mins, meaning that I want to grab all new posts **and comments** (these could be of the new posts or old ones). `instaloader` successfully allows me to grab this information but it takes a long time to grab all posts/comments, as I have to download all of this information every 30 minutes (download more than 7K posts). For example, downloading the posts/comments for a single profile with over 7K posts can take up to more than 1 or two hours.

1. Using `instaloader`, is there a way to download only the posts/comments which are new? Perhaps through HTTP etags that contain a hash for each post?
2. Is there any alternative to downloading all posts/comments quickly (let's say 1 minute)? For example, through the IG API directly or other third party APIs (https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api)?